# Can Freezer 4th form defeat SSJ2 Cabba?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

In the tournament of power, when Freezer faced Cabba, Cabba turned into SSJ2 and Freezer who was in 4th form transformed into Golden Freezer and defeated Cabba SSJ2 easily. I thought Freezer 4th form was strong enough to defeat Cabba SSJ2 but him transforming into Golden Freezer make it dubious. Can Freezer 4th form defeat SSJ2 Cabba?

Answer (score 2):

No. If you recall, Back in the ROF arc, Base Goku was easily overwhelming Final Form Frieza. Since the Golden Frieza multiplier is > Super Saiyan Blue, Frieza had the advantage. 
Frieza stated that he mastered the transformation and stopped the stamina issue with the Golden Form before the T.O.P. He never necessarily had an opportunity to train.

The Universe 6 Saiyans are very comparable to the Universe 7 Saiyans. Cabba was capable of holding his own against a Base Vegeta in his Base form. Even in Case of Caulifla, she was holding her own against SSJ, SSJ2 Goku etc. While the latter is stronger, Cabba isn't far off. Since SSJ2 is 100 * Cabba Base, Final form Frieza wouldn't stand a chance(This is because of how strong base Cabba is). Hence, he had to turn Golden to quickly finish the fight.

Comment: That part of the series is very hard to make sense. I always thought Goku was using god ki there and having a power similar to super saiyan god, though it was never stated , also Vegeta who deflected a blast from Golden Freezer in "base" form, also,  because if you remember, before, 1st form Freezer defeated SSJ Gohan, and we know 1st form Freezer is 120 times weaker than 4th form Freezer.

Comment: @Pablo Before the anime, in the movie, everybody assumed that Goku was using a "Godlike Saiyan" transformation against Frieza. This isn't canon in case of the main series. Goku had just become insanely strong in his base form. Gohan was supposed to be extremely weak at this point in time(For example A base Vegeta 2 arcs later was strong enough to beat up SSJ3 Gotenks). Hence, SSJ Gohan here was easily overwhelmed. Also, Frieza was clearly holding back the Ki Blast as he used it against Krillin and didn't expect Vegeta to react at that Speed. That is why he was able to deflect it.

Comment: @Pablo Also, the main trait with regard to God Ki is that it cannot be sensed. It was only after Goku turned into Super Saiyan Blue, everybody mentioned that Goku's ki could no longer be felt. So that was basically a Base Goku who had become very strong after learning how to use God Ki and going through Whis's difficult training. SSJ Gohan at that point was very weak and rusty and extremely weaker than Base Goku.